# How to quickly subset many dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have 180 `DataFrame` objects, each one has 3130 rows and it's about 300KB in memory.
The index is a `DatetimeIndex`, business days from 2000-01-03 to 2011-12-31:

```
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd
freq = pd.tseries.offsets.BDay()

index = pd.date_range(datetime(2000,1,3), datetime(2011,12,31), freq=freq)

df = pd.DataFrame(index=index)
df['A'] = 1000.0
df['B'] = 2000.0
df['C'] = 3000.0
df['D'] = 4000.0
df['E'] = 5000.0
df['F'] = True
df['G'] = 1.0
df['H'] = 100.0
```

I preprocess all the data taking advantage of numpy/pandas vectorization, then I have to loop through the dataframes day by day. To prevent the possibility of 'look ahead bias' and get data from the future I must be sure each day I only return a subset of my dataframes, up to that datapoint. I explain: if the current datapoint I am processing is `datetime(2010,5,15)` I need data from `datetime(2000,1,3)` to `datetime(2010,5,15)`. You should not be able to access data more recent than `datetime(2010,5,15)`. With this subset I'll make other computations I can't vectorize because they are path dependent.

I modified my original loop like this:

```
def get_data(datapoint):
    return df.loc[:datapoint]
    
calendar = df.index

for datapoint in calendar:
    x = get_data(datapoint)
```

This kind of code is painfully slow. What is my best option to improve its speed?
If I do not try to prevent the look ahead bias my production code takes about 3 minutes to run but it is too risky. With code like this it takes 13 minutes and this is unacceptable.

**%%timeit**

A slightly faster option is using `iloc` instead of `loc` but it is still slow:

```
def get_data2(datapoint):
    idx = df.index.get_loc(datapoint)
    return df.iloc[:idx]

for datapoint in calendar:
    x = get_data(datapoint)
```

371 ms ± 23.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

```
for datapoint in calendar:
    x = get_data2(datapoint)
```

327 ms ± 7.05 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

The original code, which was not trying to prevent the possibility of look ahead bias, simply returned the whole `DataFrame` when called for each datapoint. In this example is 100 time faster, real code is 4 times faster.

```
def get_data_no_check():
    return df

for datapoint in calendar:
    x = get_data_no_check()
```

2.87 ms ± 89.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

Comment: Why not just use `df.loc[:datapoint]` directly, if you have a preset datapoint value ?  Why have to loop through all indices of a dataframe ?  Looping through ALL indices and each time loc up to that index, this effectively is not subsetting anything.  Is this useful ?

Comment: This is what the code that runs in 3 minutes does but it is risky. You could be tired and put a wrong value for datapoint and you'll get data from the future, which is what I am trying to prevent

Comment: Can't you just sort the dates first to always be sure that the dates after the current are all after the current one? `df.sort_values(by='date',ascending=True)`

Comment: index is already sorted

Comment: I think you can devise method to come up with a date, just call it datapoint which is a business day and verified to be a past or present date but not future.  Then just use your df slicing to get the date range you want.

Comment: When I start the loop I have all my data preprocessed. After that, for each date/datapoint I only want to get a subset of the data from the beginning to that date/datapoint. Whith this new dataframe I'll make other computations. I edited my question to better explain.

Comment: In your added example, what's the criteria such that the dates between datetime(2010,5,5) and datetime(2010,5,15) got excluded ?   No business date within this period ?

Comment: sorry a typo. right datetime is (2010,5,15)

Comment: So you have the current datapoint pre-determined somewhere else ?  Is it possible to substitute this pre-determined date to my suggested solution replacing the datetime.now() ?  By this, my code can still help determine the latest business date within that date range.

Comment: yes it is predetermined in another place. This is why, unfortunately, your suggested solution it is not useful. The real code is 5K+ lines and thhere is a mediator pattern that manages several components. Returning data preventing the look ahead bias is my bottleneck. For each datapoint I know in advance the date so I do not have to recompute the range, I already know it.

Comment: Sorry, a bit confused.  If you know the datapoints in advance, so why you can't just plug-in the datapoint to the slice `df.loc[:datapoint]`   I guessed you have to make sure each datapoint is a business date, so suggested the code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228943/discussion-between-nicola-prada-and-seabean).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it like this: first I preprocess all my data in the `DataFrame` to take advantage of pandas vectorization then I convert it into a `dict of dict` and I iterate over it preventing the possibility of 'look ahead bias'. Since data are already preprocessed I can avoid the `DataFrame` overhead. The increase in processing speed in production code let me speechless: down from more than 30 minutes to 40 seconds!

```
# Convert the DataFrame into a dict of dict

for s, data in self._data.items():
    self._data[s] = data.to_dict(orient='index')
```

Answer (score 1):

See if this work for you:

```
datapoint_range = pd.date_range(datetime(2000,1,3), datetime.now(), freq=freq)
datapoint = datapoint_range[-1]
```

Logic is: replacing the ending date to be today so as to ensure not future date.  Then get the last date of the range.

Then use your `df.loc[:datapoint]` to get the range you want.

Comment: In my example end date is  2011-12-31. Using datetime.now() is already "future"...